# How do I copy a DataColumn from DataTable1 into DataTable2?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I would copy a `DataColumn` from a `DataTable` into a another `DataTable`, but I don't know how to do...

```
DataColumn[] dc = new DataColumn[DataTable1.Columns.Count];
DataTable1.Columns.CopyTo(dc, 0);
DataTable2.Columns.Add(dc[index]);
```

Error

> DataColumn belongs to another DataTable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now! Removing the columns was a realy bad idea!

Much better for the columns in a DataTable:

```
DataGrid2.Columns[index].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
DataGrid2.Columns[index].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

And for the rows in an DataTable:

```
DataRow dataRow = DataTable2.NewRow();
object o = DataTable1.Rows[index].ItemArray.GetValue(index);
dataRow.SetField(index, o);
DataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, 0);

((DataRowView)(DataGrid2.Items[index])).Row.Delete();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DataView.ToTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx) method that accepts the column names that you want to have in your new table.

```
 DataTable DataTable2 = DataTable1.DefaultView.ToTable(false, new string[] {"CustomerName"});
```

Keep in mind that this creates a new DataTable from your original table with only the column specified in the string array (of course the original table should have a column named "CustomerName")

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand. What about an example?

Comment: The code above creates a new datatable variable named DataTable2 that contains a single column named "CustomerName" (just as an example). The name is taken from the first DataTable and all the data values (rows) of this first table's column are copied in the single column present in the second table. Perhaps if you have more code to show, for example: how do you fill your table, what column names are present in your DataTable1 then I could be more precise thant this.

Comment: DataTable dt = DataTable1.DefaultView.ToTable(false, DataTable.Columns[index].ToString());
DataTable2.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[0]);

Comment: Error: DataColumn belongs to another DataTable!

Comment: So DT2 is an existing table (with its own columns I suppose) and you want to add the first column to DT2 and, of course, you want to have also the data copied with the column?  Could you explain better what are your intentions with this column at index 0 of the first table?

Comment: DataTable1 and DataTable2 are not only existing tables, they are containing the same data. DataTable2 does not contain all columns, DataTable1 with maybe 20 columns, DataTable2 maybe with the first 10 columns. And now I would like to add the column 11 from DT1 to DT2

Comment: The situation then is a lot more complicated. You need to manually add the columns missing in the DataTable2 (this means creating the column with the same name and type and adding it to the DataTable2), then you could use LoadDataRow method but this to work its magic needs to have the primary key on the destination table correctly set